# Test statistic as Gamma distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, gamma-distribution

I want to perform a simulation study where I want to use gamma random variable
as the test statistic for some test. Does anyone know a hypothesis test whose 
test statistic has a gamma distribution.

Comment: You might find it useful to know that the [chi-squared distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution) is a Gamma distribution.

Comment: That certainly solves the problem! Thanks for the reminder.